# Как распарсить строку в которой лежит xml. Android

Tags: java, android, xml, строки

Приходит строка в виде xml

```
String a =
   "<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <answer>
        <name>Винт DIN 965 M4*16(2000 шт)</name>
        <balance>Отсутствует</balance>
        <code>00-00000029</code>
    </answer>"
```

как мне из неё достать данные в отдельные переменные?  Или же как создать xml файл на основе этой строки?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что я нашёл, всё работает чики-пуки

```
 try {


                                        XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
                                        XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();
                                        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(ss));

                                        Document doc = (Document) xpath.evaluate("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
                                        postName = xpath.evaluate("/answer/name", doc);
                                        postBalance = xpath.evaluate("/answer/balance", doc);
                                        String bal = xpath.evaluate("/answer/code", doc);
                                        tvPost.setText(postName);
                                        tvPostBalance.setText(postBalance);

                                    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
```